# How to enable delta qp flag while encoding with HEVC?

Tags: hevc, libx265

I am encoding a video file with HEVC (open source X.265 downloaded from bitbucket).
I am using this CLI argument:

```
--qp 38 -b 0 -p ultrafast --psnr  --input-res 1280x720 --fps 24 --frames 120 --merange 32 --no-lft  --subme 0  --input Input.yuv --output OutputFile_22.hevc --recon YuvRecon.yuv
```

How can I enable delta QP flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be possible to enable delta QP when encoding in Fixed QP configuration by providing --qp option. When encoder is configured to Rate Control mode, then use --aq-mode to enable Sub-Frame level QP modification. Further details can be found about different CLI parameters at http://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/cli.html